# How to re-open internet explorer and resume vba web scraping if it is closed by mistake or error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of urls to get data from using the following.

```
lastrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ie.Visible = True

For i = 2 To lastrow


    mylink = wks.Cells(i, 2).Value
    t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        ie.Navigate2 mylink

        While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        On Error Resume Next
        Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.in-stock ")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop While availability Is Nothing

    If Not availability Is Nothing Then
        wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 38

        Set product_sku = ie.Document.querySelector(".single-product__sku")
        wks.Cells(i, "A").Value = product_sku.innerText
        Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".price .woocommerce-Price-amount")
        wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = price.innerText
        wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = availability.innerText
        Set product_name = ie.Document.querySelector(".single-product__title")
        wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = product_name.innerText


        Set price = Nothing: Set availability = Nothing '.... etc
    End If
    wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Next i

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
```

Sometimes IE stops working and I have to stop the module and restart manually, or maybe I close it by mistake.

How to resume the module and continue from where it stopped?

Comment: Can you discern *why* or *when* IE stops working? Is it after a set number of URLs?

Comment: If you're somehow accidentally clicking close on IE, you could try `IE.Visible = False`. But it's probably better to address why it "stops working".

Comment: I am guessing maybe it is something with the server of URL? it just says IE not responding so I am forced to close it, its a timeout? I dont know

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes I notice it is happening after 20-30 URLs

Comment: Would slipping a `DoEvents` just before `Next i` help?

Comment: maybe you close it by mistake? How so? @MathieuGuindon's suggestion is a good one. Also, does it make a difference to first a dimension an array related to your url count and populate that with all your info and then do all your writing out and sheet formatting at the end? Separate out the web stuff from the sheet stuff and then see if you can fine tune where it is hanging.

Comment: and how can I do that?